# What to conclude when the effect size is low in AB test and it takes very long to reach minimum sample size

Tags: statistical-significance, ab-test

1. We typically calculate the minimum sample size in our AB tests, based on the effect size we see between the test and control buckets (as minimum sample size is inverse to effect size, given power and alpha) - will run for at least 30-45 days though which is more than our usual season.

Is this a valid approach? because we are not concerned about specific effect size, but concerned if there is significant difference between the test and control

2. Also, we typically run the tests between 45-60 days and we get minimum sample size. But, for some tests the effect size is very low and also the population being bucket is only a fraction of the total population hence it will take many months to get minimum sample size and we therefore stop the tests after 60 days. What can we conclude in this case ? no significant difference or is the test inconclusive ? IS there a way to test for significant differences for small sample sizes, which takes where long to get minimum sample size.

Comment: To me it seems on the edge of P-hacking. Hope it's not.

Comment: @BruceET, sorry not quite sure, what you meant, can you please elaborate

Comment: Maybe look into [tag:sequential-analysis] or control charts